# Wearable GPS Antenna

Tags: arduino-uno, gps

I am using the Adafruit Fona 808 to make a wearable device. One of the main features is GPS but I cannot seem to find a suitable antenna for wearables. My question is: What is a good GPS antenna for a wearable project and should it be active or passive?
Thanks

Comment: Whats wrong with the recommended antenna on the product page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I too thought whats wrong with a normal Antenna, but the answer is the problem is the human body.

There are manufacturers that make "fabric" antennas, but these tend to be Mil-Spec so are going to cost a fortune.  (http://www.pharad.com/gps-wearable-antenna.html)

I found this site that explains what the effect of the body is, and seems to make their own antenna.  http://www.pharad.com/gps-wearable-antenna.html

I think you might be better off looking for a high gain antenna and the choice of active or passive will probably be based on the interference you get from the body.